# Terraform interactive input doesn't work with the root module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

#### Terraform Version

```
Terraform v1.1.2
on windows_amd64
```

#### Terraform Configuration Files

**child_module1.tf(C1):**

```
# Create Resource Group
resource "aws_resourcegroups_group" "resourcegroups_group" {
  name = "test"

  resource_query {
    query = <<JSON
{
  "ResourceTypeFilters": [
    "AWS::EC2::Instance"
  ],
  "TagFilters": [
    {
      "Key": "project",
      "Values": ["${var.ProjectName}"]
    }
  ]
}
JSON
  }
}
```

**child_module1_variables.tf:**

```
########
variable "ProjectName" {
  type = string
  description = "This name would be prefixed with the cluster names."
}
```

Now call this child module in another child module**(C2)**:
**child_module2.tf:**

```
module "prepare_aws_cloud" {
      source                        = "./modules/aws/prepare_cloud_copy"
      ProjectName                   = "${var.test.ProjectName}"
}
```

**child_module2_variables.tf:**

```
variable "test" {
  type = object({
    ProjectName                 = string
  })
}
```

**Now I create a root module**(R1)** which calls the child_module2.tf:**

```
 terraform {
  backend "local" {
   }
 }
 module "test_deploy" {
   source = "D:\\REPO\\installer_v2.2.22.1\\installer\\aws"

   
test = {
    #ProjectName                 = ""
}

 }
```

So the dependency is as follows:
R1 calls >> C2 calls >> C1

#### ERROR

```
PS D:\tkgTest> terraform apply -input=true
╷
│ Error: Invalid value for module argument
│
│   on testing.tf line 21, in module "test_deploy":
│   21: test= {
│   22:     #ProjectName                 = ""
│   23: }
│
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable "test" defined at .terraform\modules\test_deploy\variables.tf:108,1-15: attribute "ProjectName" is required.
```

#### Expected Behavior

I would have expected that the user input would be taken interactively by the console as I am passing the `-input=true` flag but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Terraform rejects empty strings on a required String variable. The`-input`  flag works for variables if not already set. So, you need to define a `ProjectName` variable for the R1  root module and pass it to  C2 module `test =   { ProjectName = "${var.ProjectName}" }`.  Doing so, the -input flag will prompt you to enter th root module `ProjectName` variable value if not set in a tfvars file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interactive prompts for input variables are intended only to help with getting started with Terraform (e.g. following a simple tutorial) and so they are limited in the scope of what they support. The typical way to set root module input variables for routine use is to either create a `.tfvars` file and pass it to Terraform with `-var-file` or to set a variable directly using `-var`.

Note also that only *root module* input variables can be set directly as part of the planning options. Any child module variables are defined exclusively by the expressions written in the `module` block, and so if you want to be able to set a child module's input variable on a per-run basis you'll need to also declare it as a root module variable and then pass it through to the child module.

For example, in the root module:

```
variable "test" {
  type = object({
    ProjectName                 = string
  })
}

module "test_deploy" {
  source = "./installer/aws"

  test = var.test
}
```

You can then create an `example.tfvars` file with the following to set a value for the variable:

```
test = {
  ProjectName = "example"
}
```

Specify that file when you run Terraform:

```
terraform apply -var-file=example.tfvars
```

If you will always set the same values then you can avoid the need for the extra option by naming your file `example.auto.tfvars` and placing it in the same directory where you will run Terraform. Terraform will load `.auto.tfvars` files automatically without any explicit `-var-file` option.